how to exclude request api url in spring netty access log
I currently have netty's access-log running in the following way.
System.setProperty("reactor.netty.http.server.accessLogEnabled", "true")
However, the current Spring Actuator's health log is loaded too frequently in the log storage file, so I would like to exclude URL calls to /health from the log record. Is there a way?

You can use a filter for access log.
@Component
public class MyNettyWebServerCustomizer
        implements WebServerFactoryCustomizer<NettyReactiveWebServerFactory> {
    @Override
    public void customize(NettyReactiveWebServerFactory factory) {
        factory.addServerCustomizers(httpServer ->
            httpServer.accessLog(true, AccessLogFactory.createFilter(p ->
                    !String.valueOf(p.uri()).startsWith("/health/"))));
    }
}

More info you can find here
